# Flutter FlutterBluePlus 1.7.3 can not use about ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Tags: flutter

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled
> Exception: PlatformException(startScan, FlutterBluePlus requires
> android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission, null, null)

android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.fit.monster">
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="true" /> 
   
   <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/tergasy"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
       
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
                <!-- <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              /> -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"  android:maxSdkVersion="30"/>  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"  android:maxSdkVersion="30"/>  
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"  android:maxSdkVersion="30"/> 
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"  android:maxSdkVersion="30"/>
</manifest>
```

I have been in accordance with the requirements, add all the permissions, but there is no android bluetooth still hint. Permission. ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, apple version is no problem, just android version has been the problem. I'll just change flutter_blue_plus: ^1.4.0 back to 1.4.0. But the problem remains unresolved. Do any of your buddies have the same problem?